# How to Insert BOOL Value to MySQL Database

Tags: mysql

I am trying to insert values into a `BOOL` data type in MySQL (v 5.5.20) using the following script:

```
CREATE DATABASE DBTest;
USE DBTest;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS first;
CREATE TABLE first (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY , name VARCHAR(30) ,sale  BOOL,); 
INSERT INTO first VALUES ("", "G22","TRUE");
INSERT INTO first VALUES ("", "G23","FALSE");
```

But the  `INSERT` statement just inserts `0` (Zero) to the boolean column for both `TRUE` and `FALSE` options! Can you please let me know why this is happening?

Comment: Note that BOOL, BOOLEAN field types in MySQL are really just aliases for TINYINT(1).  Many find it better to work with `0` and `1` as values for insert such that it is explicitly clear what you are trying to do in the code (i.e. not depending on casting behavior)

Answer (score 70, accepted):

`TRUE` and `FALSE` are keywords, and should not be quoted as strings:

```
INSERT INTO first VALUES (NULL, 'G22', TRUE);
INSERT INTO first VALUES (NULL, 'G23', FALSE);
```

By quoting them as strings, MySQL will then cast them to their integer equivalent (since booleans are really just a one-byte `INT` in MySQL), which translates into  zero for any non-numeric string. Thus, you get `0` for both values in your table.

#### Non-numeric strings cast to zero:

```
mysql> SELECT CAST('TRUE' AS SIGNED), CAST('FALSE' AS SIGNED), CAST('12345' AS SIGNED);
+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| CAST('TRUE' AS SIGNED) | CAST('FALSE' AS SIGNED) | CAST('12345' AS SIGNED) |
+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
|                      0 |                       0 |                   12345 |
+------------------------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

#### But the keywords return their corresponding `INT` representation:

```
mysql> SELECT TRUE, FALSE;
+------+-------+
| TRUE | FALSE |
+------+-------+
|    1 |     0 |
+------+-------+
```

Note also, that I have replaced your double-quotes with single quotes as are more standard SQL string enclosures.  Finally, I have  replaced your empty strings for `id` with `NULL`.  The empty string may issue a warning.

Comment: Hi Michael, Thanks for your hints but the table still displaying 0 even when I just did like`code`INSERT INTO first VALUES (NULL, 'G22', TRUE);`code`

Comment: @user1760110 That seems unlikely. Here's a demonstration with 5.5.28  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1fc2a/1